QGIS Boolean styling breaks when scratch layer permanent
For a project I'm working on I was asked to solve this problem. The layout the company uses starts with a scratch layer for adding points by default. When adding points a boolean option was added which would add extra styling to the point (e.g. blue background when set to true). This all works fine in the scratch layer, but when making the layer permanent the extra styling won't show up anymore when adding new points. When looking at the attribute table you can see that the True/False is registered, but the extra styling is no longer added on the map. The original point symbols do show up and when drawing points with the additional boolean option when still in the scratch layer it does carry over to the permanent layer. Any idea how to fix this? I've tried making the layer permanent both as a shapefile or geopackage.
Im using QGIS 3.40.1

Note that "styling" is not saved while making a layer permanent ("styling" is a broad term, as it refers to symbology, labels, attribute form, ...). You can either use the tool "Package layers" (with the option of saving the styling to the geopackage) or you can copy the symbology (right click on your scratch layer > Styles > Copy Style > e.g., Symbology) to your new layer (right click on new layer > Styles > Paste Style > e.g., Symbology)

hey thanks, this did not solve it yet, but makes it a little bit more clear for me. So what you are saying that when making the layer permanent i'm not saving the styling, but only the vector data that i've drawn on the scratch layer? I will try some other stuff first and rephrase my question if the problem persists

Yes it saves the vector data as well as added field values. Basically the attribute table + geometry. How do you create your symbology? And how are the boolean options added?

When you say "making the layer permanent", do you literally use the context menu option "Make permanent" or do you "Export" the scratch layer? Using "Make permanent" should continue using symbology settings you applied when the layer was in-memory. But as @Fjedsen mentions, a new layer created by exporting will not keep the symbology.

@Fjedsen, I think I found the source of the problem by comparing the fields in both the scratch and permament layer. When making the layer permanent the boolean fields are carried over just fine. The scratch field holds a expression field, which returns a string if one of the boolean fields is set to true. This expression field is coupled to the symbology. When making the layer permanent, the expression is lost and the field is just converted to a regular text field. So adding new points with the boolean values set to "true", won't add a symbol, because the expression is gone.

I also tried readding the expression with no succes,  it seems to me that scratch layers offer way more field options then shape or gpkg layers, so I guess I need a workaround.

@Matt I do indeed use the context menu option, "Make permanent"

It sounds like you could make use of a Virtual Field which can use an expression. Bear in mind that these fields are not saved on the data provider, but, rather within the current project.

Hey Matt, I guess this is the case. I now fixed it using rule-based symbology instead of this virtual field, now everything keeps functioning when making the layer permanent. I wonder why the previous guy who made this used the virtual field at all, maybe there is a reason and I will find out later, but hey, it works now! Thanks both Matt and Fjedsen for your insight and a happy new year :)
